# Is it a good idea to keep database migration inside VCS?

Tags: database, django, database-design, data-migration, django-south

The conventional wisdom seems to be that database migrations should be kept inside the VCS - that way there is a record of all the changes the database went through.

But...

What is the use of having old migrations? I don't really see myself reverting to the old version of db. Wouldn't it be easier to just keep them out of the VCS, and create a migration queue on every machine that doesn't have to be kept in sync with everybody else's migraton queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think keeping old migrations around is waste then you don't understand migrations.  Migrations allow you to rollback a change.  You might not imagine doing it, but it can be necessary.  Full migration histories allow collaborative teams to remain in sync regardless of version they might have when they start.

Trashing and starting over is one of the worst things you can do with South.  You completely screw up other developers unless you explicitly tell everyone to go in and clear out the south_migrationhistory table and delete all the existing migrations and create a new init migration.

In short.  Leave migrations in VCS, it's where they belong so that anyone coming into a project from any point can quickly migrate their db to the current version.  Don't clean them out, they don't hurt anything and you create hassles for other collaborators by doing so.

Comment: What about working in small teams, or even single-programmer teams. Would you say migration history is equally important?

Comment: Yes, because you may have collaborators in the future and it's a good habit...and again they don't hurt anything so why blow them up?  And it still let's you roll back the database for deployment if something goes wrong.

Comment: You use VCS and you certainly don't need VCS for a small team right?  Do you regularly export and recreate your GIT/SVN repo?

Comment: Think of migrations as being kinda like VCS for your database schema.  They represent diffs between versions in the same way a commit represents a change set.  You don't clean out your revision history (I hope), so why would you clean out your migration history?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right there is little use in keeping old migrations, even if they do no harm I also do not like unused code in my projects.

While using a migration system like south helps a lot during development it is true that you are probably not going to need old schema migrations about consolidated features/changes (and in case you still have the model changes in python code available on the VCS).

From time to time I do trash and recreate all migration in one single initial migration and start again to collect new migrations.

Keeping migration outside of the VCS is not a good idea at it will probably if it is not going introduce problems it will slow down development for sure.

EDIT:
Since the clean up process involves the team to be aware of this reorganization (and clear the migration history table) it is not suggested to do so when you can't reach easily all developers/users.